# Does TLS support lightweight cryptography defined by IOS/IEC 29192 standard?

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography, tls1.2, lightweight-processes

does TLS support any of the lightweight cryptographic primitives defined in  IOS/IEC 29192? like Clefia, Present or any others?

Comment: This is not a programming/development question, but a move to security.SX or maybe crypto.SX would be (much) better than superuser as the vote is suggesting. And PS: it's ISO/IEC.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [TLS 1.2 cipher suites](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) You will see that it is not containing any lightweight ciphers.

The [TLS 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-tls13-28) actually has only 5 cipher suites. Due to the birthday attack on small block sized block ciphers, see [sweet32](https://sweet32.info/), they are not even suitable for TLS, anymore.

The ChaCha20 as mentioned by Dave is a stream cipher.

Comment: "Lightweight" cryptography is a new/recent criterion and means basically "works on very limited CPUs" for example RFID tags. It has nothing to do with blocksize and [3]DES and Blowfish are not lightweight; ChaCha _may_ be (also Salsa, but that isn't supported in TLS). Note there are lots of <=1.2 suites in RFCs other than 5246 et pred; the registry at IANA is a better reference.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh there is a mistake calling them lightweight, thanks. The Present block cipher goes back to 2007. Yes they are designed for limited...